# Simplify DDD entity class state transitioning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to develop application the DDD way, for the first time.

I've got an entity class that can have multiple states and has rules to follow in order to transition from one state to another. I've got a dictionary where keys are states entity can transition to and values are states that state can be transitioned from:

```
protected static readonly IDictionary<State, State[]> aGoodName = new Dictionary<State, State[]>
{
    { State.Approved, new State[] { State.Requested } },
    { State.Standardized, new State[] { State.Approved } },
    { State.Queued, new State[] { State.Standardized, State.Succeeded, State.Failed } },
    { State.Running, new State[] { State.Queued } },
    { State.Succeeded, new State[] { State.Running } },
    { State.Failed, new State[] { State.Running } },
    { State.Completed, new State[] { State.Succeeded } },
    { State.Canceled, new State[] { State.Requested, State.Approved, State.Standardized, State.Succeeded, State.Failed, State.Queued } }
};
```

I've got one generic method that has desired state as a parameter and checks whether it can be transitioned from:

```
public void Transition(State state)
{
    if (!aGoodName[state].Contains(State))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot change state from {State.ToString()} to {state.ToString()}.");
    }

    State = state;
}
```

However, if I understand correctly, the DDD way is to express domain code in language that would both developers and business people understand to a degree so for instance it would make more sense to have a method, let's say for succession:

```
public void Succeed()
{
    Transition(State.Succeeded);
}
```

Or even:

```
public void Succeed()
{
    var states = new List<State> { State.Running };

    if (!states.Contains(State))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot change state from {State.ToString()} to {State.Succeeded.ToString()}.");
    }

    State = State.Succeeded;
}
```

I'm fairly new to this design pattern and would like to know which of approaches above is most suitable for DDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to your question depends on another question first:

- How these states are important in your domain?

What is important here is to consider the domain literature (aka Ubiquitous Language) in the design. But the implementation details actually depends on the importance of the issue. They could be even independent entities!

```
entity.To(new ApprovedState());
```

If the state transition is just a flag data, then the first implementation you provided here could be enough, but if it's more important and has more business rules surround it, you can use the second implementation, or patterns like State or Strategy.

```
interface IState{...}

class Approved : IState {...}

class Requested : IState {...}

class Entity{
   public IState State {get; set;}
}
```

Finally you can provide a thin layer of fluent API to express your domain more delicately (of course you can design it this way too...):

```
TheEntity.IfItsPossible().Approve();
```

### Update

There is one more thing here. Sometimes we add fields to our entities just like we do the same to the tables in databases. That's how things work in db world! But I think that's quite different in DDD. Maybe these different states actually play the role of different entities or hidden business rules which needs to be digged deeper. Suppose *Request* is not a state of Reload entity, but it is an entity by itself that people create when they need to have a Reload. Just like when you create an order when you need to buy a product.

```
public class Reload
{
}

public class Request
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    // and other logics about requests
}

public interface IFactory
{
    Reload Create(Request request);
}
```

If that's really whats happening in the domain, then these states are nothing but the result of inner workings of other entities and domain-services. For example the *Standardized* state is what we call the Reloads that are waiting to be processed in the queue, and you can query these kind of information from modules of the application:

```
public interface IQueueService
{
    void Push(Reload reload);
}


public IEnumerable<Reload> GetStandardizedReloads()
{
    return _queueService.Items();  
}

public IEnumerable<Request> GetRequests()
{
    return _requestRepository.GetAll();
}
```

Comment: There is no hidden business logic within each step, it's really just a path to transition to Completed/Canceled. What matters most is authorization, but that's handled in API controller. I'll check state and strategy patterns. Also if I were to use an entity for each state, how would I retrieve them from my repository in a case, when I need to return multiple states?

Comment: Well if it's an entity it can have it's own repository and you can retrieve them just like other entities. It really gets interesting when it comes to issues like authorization. Because states in scenarios like this is not Cross-Cutting concern, but it sounds like them!  What is your "Entity"? Explain the domain please.

Comment: We call it a `Reload`. It's a simple ETL process from internal research application to client-facing application. Creating a `Reload` means it's requested, then authorized people can approve it, data quality team `Standardizes` and puts that request in a queue where background process will deal with these requests one by one. Once the background process finishes, it's being set to `Succeeded`/`Failed` and then we decide whether it goes to production or not. That's really just a release pipeline, but for data.

Comment: I see. Suppose you do not have any State field in the Reload class. Can you query the state of a Reload object? For example, a standardized Reload is a Reload that is being processed in the queue. Or there is no such a thing as Requested state. Instead you have a ReloadRequest entity, and etc...  Specifying this kind of flag data for entities usually comes from the data-driven design paradigm. I'm not sure if this case is like that, but this kind of questions usually leads to a better design.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understood your question. _Can you query the state of a Reload object?_

Comment: What you said totally makes sense. I've come from database background and designing entity as a _table_ made sense to me. Thanks for your help and putting me on the right track!